# What domain service to use with my VPS hosting?

Tags: domain-registration

I've bought a VPS hosting with slicehosting.com

They do not provide domains registration. I was wondering what's the ideal domain service to use together with slicehost.com ?

thanks

Comment: did you mean slicehost.com?

Comment: @NARKOZ yes I corrected my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Slicehosting but in general you should be able to use any domain name service provider. I used GoDaddy - the prices are good.

Answer (score 0):

absolutely anything with DNS management built in. 123-reg or fasthosts domain registration should be fine for you assuming you want a .uk, .com, .net, .org or other common domain names as they come with a free DNS hosting service.

Answer (score 0):

I've had great success with [namecheap.com](http://www.namecheap.com) . It is easy to make changes to your DNS records.

I have used this site with slicehost.